# Entity reference default value to first value

Tags: entities, users

I have an entity reference field using a view to dynamically create a list based on a contextual filter from a user ID in URL. Works perfectly.

Question is, how can I default the value to the first result in the list, instead of displaying -None- or -Please select-

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily using jQuery

```
$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());
```

Comment: Sure, jQuery was a last resort. Thanks for your answer though.